# Json polymorphism deserialization

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON file to my classes in Java. I have tried all possible solutions I could find with the JSON annotations, such as `@JsonSubTypes`, `@JsonTypeInfo` and with CLASS, NAME and all I can find. However, none of the solutions worked.

Please see below the raw JSON file and classes before the changes.

JSON file:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
        "error_msg": "error msg 1",
        "error_code": "error code 1",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "data": [
          {
            "error_msg": "error msg 2",
            "error_code": "error code 2",
            "type": "error"
          }
        ],
        "name": "group1",
        "type": "group"
     }
  ],
  "name": "exceptions_db",
  "version": "1"
}
```

Java classes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionsModel implements JsonModel{
    private String version;
    private String name;
    private List<ExceptionItem> data;

    public void setData(List<ExceptionItem> data) {
        if (data.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data array must contain at least one item");
        }
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Error extends ExceptionItem {
    private String error_msg;
    private String error_code;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Group extends ExceptionItem {
    private String name;
    private List<ExceptionItem> data;

    public Group(String name, List<ExceptionItem> data) {
        if (data.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data array must contain at least one item");
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(List<ExceptionItem> data) {
        if (data.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data array must contain at least one item");
        }
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class ExceptionItem {
}
```

Each item in my model and JSON, under data property, can be either a group or error object.

UPDATE:

I have tried to add the json annotations to ExceptionItem but still did not work

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Error.class, name = "error"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Group.class, name = "group"),
})
public abstract class ExceptionItem {
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Can not construct instance of com.altair.infrastructures.propertiesFile.jsonResourceLoader.exceptions.ExceptionItem, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: C:\QA\TestCaseGenerator\systemFiles\exceptions\Exceptions_DB.json; line: 3, column: 5] (through reference chain: com.altair.infrastructures.propertiesFile.jsonResourceLoader.exceptions.ExceptionsModel["data"])
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with my ObjectMapper that was from package org.codehaus.jackson and my JSON annotations were from fasterxml